# z-index doesn't seem to work normally at smaller sizes

Tags: image, width

I have some fairly complex stacking arrangements going on in a site I'm working on. With a background image on a div being a gradient that overlays an image within it with a lower zindex. Like this:

[image]

So, this works fine at larger widths. When the width is smaller the image appears over the gradient background, like this:

[image]

Something's happening and I can't figure out what. I'm using twitter Bootstrap 2.3.0 as a framework. Link: http://www.osullivans-pubs.com/draft

EDIT: I'm pretty sure the problem is something to do with having a negative z-index on the image (#back img). But having the z-index at zero means the image appears above the gradient...

UPDATE: I worked it out. It's not really possible to have an element with a background image overlap a child element. So I created an absolutely positioned element before (and seperate from) the container and applied the appropriate zindex to that. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a z-index in liquid-slider.css file below is the code...

```
.liquid-slider-wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto;
   clear: both;
   overflow: auto;
   position: relative;
   width: 1110px !important;
   z-index: 20;
}
```